# Mediawiki 1.27.4 jquery not loaded

Tags: jquery, mediawiki

I am new to the Mediawiki and Resourceloader stuff. I recently downloaded MediaWiki 1.27.4 LTS version and When installed, I found that even if they say, jquery is loaded by default, it is nowhere to be found (I am looking into sources tab in chrome developer tools). 
In one of my extensions which uses BeforePageDisplay hook, I wanted to use jquery.cookie so I declared the following resourceloader

```
$wgResourceModules['ext.myFirstExtension'] = array(           
        'dependencies' => array( 'jquery.cookie'),            
        'localBasePath' => dirname( __FILE__ ),            
        'remoteExtPath' => 'myFirstExtension',
        'position' => 'top'
);
```

And in my extension file, I am autoloading one of the class and in which, I am executing the 
In the script, I am simply executing the following code, and it throws me typical error of $ undefined since jquery is not loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("here");
});
```

And yes, I am using a Vector skin without any modifications. In addition, I am not using any other extensions except VisualEditor and it works beautifully fine.

I also tried mw.loader.load('jquery') in my  and it also complains that mw is not recognized.

I also added $wgResourceLoaderDebug = true; in my localsettings so that resource loader doesn't bundle up my scripts and css

I suspect that Mediawiki internally can't function without jquery.. but now how can I get jquery to load in my extension correctly so that I can use jquery.cookie.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the `'position' => 'top'` option of your module registration, which probably causes it to load even before than jQuery.

There's generally no reason to use `'position' => 'top'`, unless the resource is a CSS-only module.

Comment: Ciencia, I tried your suggestions and it is not working. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery will be loaded only when there is any JQuery code to be executed in Common.js, or in the user's custom vector.js page.

Before you import any external libraries you have to make sure that JQuery works, follow these lazy steps:

1. add following to your LocalSettings.php file.

> $wgAllowUserJs = true;

2. Go to your account custom vector.js page (i.e. user:/vector.js) and type any JQuery code like

`$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("here");
});`

After saving the page, it must alert the browser with "here" word.

If Not then you should check if Javascript is enabled in your browser, also if you import JQuery cookies through URL then check that the URL is running through https protocol, since MediaWiki will not accept any external sources that not apply https protocol.

Comment: ASammour, I looked at the vector.js and its first line itself starts with jquery anonymous function jQuery( function ( $ ) {.....}) so looks like jquery is loaded by default. When I put $(document).ready(function(){...}), it executes just fine. But same piece of code in my extensionis not working. May be I am using inline javascript in extension's "execute" method?? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling to make the jquery work in extension class, I decided to create a trial extension to prove theory that I was thinking might be the case:

Here is my extension file:

```
<?php
# Alert the user that this is not a valid entry point to MediaWiki if they try to access the special pages file directly.
if (!defined('MEDIAWIKI')) {
    echo <<<EOT
To install my extension, put the following line in LocalSettings.php:
require_once( "$IP/extensions/MyExtension/MyExtension.php" );
EOT;
    exit( 1 );
}

$wgExtensionCredits['specialpage'][] = array(
    'path' => __FILE__,
    'name' => 'TryExtension',
    'author' => 'Andy',
    'url' => 'https://home.com',
    'descriptionmsg' => 'Trial Extension',
    'version' => '1.0.0',
);

$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';

$wgAutoloadClasses['TryExtension'] = $dir . 'tryExtension.class.php'; # Location of the SpecialMyExtension class (Tell MediaWiki to load this file)

$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = 'TryExtension::execute';

$wgResourceModules['ext.TryExtension'] = array(    
    'scripts' => array('scripts/tryjQuery.js'),    
    'dependencies' => array( 'jquery.cookie'),    
    'localBasePath' => dirname( __FILE__ ),    
    'remoteExtPath' => 'TryExtension',
    'position' => 'top'
);
```

Here is my javascript file that is included with an extension:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("here");
    });
```

And here is the extension class:

```
<?php
class TryExtension extends SpecialPage
{
 public function execute(){
     global $wgOut;
     $wgOut->addModules( 'ext.TryExtension' );
    ?>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("from class - here");
    }); 
    </script>
     <?php
 }
}
```

And guess what?
alert from js file works great... but not from extension. It throws referenceError $ is undefined.

I believe, I will have to move my all inline js code to dedicated javascript files for better or worse. 
That was not the case in 1.24.x version of MediaWiki. Now I believe, lot of my extensions needs lot of work.